# Querying files with objectId using Parse doesn't work

Tags: php, parse-platform

I want to display a file that's stored in the class "UserPhoto" in the database, and I have the objectId of that file.

However, if I do this:

```
$image = "objectIdOfTheFile";
$query = new ParseQuery("UserPhoto");
$query->equalTo("objectId",$image);
$results = $query->find();
```

`$results` actually returns an empty array. I looked through the documentation of Parse but couldn't fin anything that suggests to use another way. I then try to get the file URL using:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++)
{
    $imagefile = $results[$i]->getURL();
}
```

But since `$results` is empty `$imagefile` is always empty.

The strange thing is that this works with JavaScript and with Obj-C as well. Any help would be gladly appreciated!

Comment: That may be useless... but can you try to var_dump the $image var? Is is correctly formed?

Answer (score 0):

To get the `ParseObject` by the `objectId`, [you should use `ParseQuery::get()`](https://www.parse.com/docs/php_guide#objects-retrieving):

```
$image = "objectIdOfTheFile";
$query = new ParseQuery("UserPhoto");
try {
    $imageObject = $query->get($image);
} catch (ParseException $ex) {
  // The object was not retrieved successfully.
  // error is a ParseException with an error code and message.
}
```

Comment: I get the object not found error, even when I hardcode an `objectId` from the database by just copy + pasting (with surrounding " of course). Could that have any to do with user access rights?

Comment: @Andre Or a mistyped object ID. Can you try any other object?

Comment: I've tried around 10 different ID's, still no luck.

Comment: @Andre And the objects are currently set to "Public Read/Write" on the ACL?

Comment: No. So it's the ACL. But I preferably don't have Public Read on, but afaik there is no master key to use for the PHP SDK right? So I guess I'll have to..

Comment: @Andre Or maybe you just [have to log in](https://www.parse.com/docs/php_guide#users-login) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$date= $object->getCreatedAt();
        $CreatedAt=array();
        foreach($date as $key => $val)
        {
          $CreatedAt[$key] = $val;
        }
```